# Can I have a webform in sidebar block reload current page

Tags: 7, blocks, webforms, redirection

I have a webform in my sidebar as a block. If I set `Redirection location` to `No redirect (reload current page)`, it loads the form url in the main content. I can understand why it's doing this, but I would like it to reload the current page instead (or submit the form with AJAX but that's not necessary). Is there any simple way of achieving this?

Answer (score 11):

This is an old question, but it comes up high in search results, so I thought I'd provide an answer.

The behavior you've described is the intended behavior. The [module maintainer states](http://drupal.org/node/1337784#comment-5366368) that the original implementation of the `No Redirect` option was designed "under the assumption that if you were starting a form you'd enter minimal information (such as an e-mail address) to start the form, then you'd want the rest of the form on a larger page."

To achieve *your* desired behavior (i.e., reload whatever page the block form is submitted from), you need to take [one extra step](http://drupal.org/node/1337784#comment-5324442): From the block configuration page, check the box for `Show all webform pages in block` and save the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Drupal and webforms are you using?
I don't remember what D6 allowed, but in D7 you can set a custom redirection and use a token to control what the redirect is.

You would want to get the URL of the current page (i.e. with a token like %request) and redirect to that.

Comment: drupal 7 webForms 7.x-3.15  I will look into token replacements, though i'm not easily finding a reference with what can go in there

Comment: Go to the "webform" tab of your form and click the "TOKEN VALUES" triangle under the redirection field.
There is a %request token which will allow you to get the current request information, but it looks like it is only available to authorized users.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I can only see this below the redirection location options: "_Choose where to redirect the user upon successful submission. The Custom URL option supports Webform token replacements._" However I cannot see an option for redirection when the submission is unsuccessful. Please advise, thanks very much.